# jquery ui - calendar year color overridden by bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

My jQuery UI calender's css styles are overridden by the bootstrap css styles.

See the following snapshot... the calendar's year text color is not black.

[image]

The reason is, bootstrap css are overriding the jQuery css. In browser developer view, if I uncheck the style marked in red, then the style in green arrow gets enabled and everything looks normal.

[image]

**Question:**

How should I fix this issue in the css? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various rules governing the order that CSS is processed in. Generally, when two rules apply to the same element, the rule called *LAST* will supercede the rule called *FIRST*.

Thus, in your case, I would suggest loading **jquery-ui.css** *after* **bootstrap.css**.

The order in your `<head>` should be:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/jquery-ui.css">
```

**Notes:**

Another reason why jquery-ui.css should be place after bootstrap.css is style structure. Bootstrap.css governs the entirety of your document, it is a style and structure framework, while jquery-ui.css is intended to apply only to select elements.

Alternatively, if your aim is to modify the jQuery UI element, I would recommend creating a custom stylesheet (also placed after both documents), as opposed to altering jquery-ui.css or bootstrap-ui.css. However, this is just to maintain a best practice approach.

And as a final (and sloppy) alternative, apply `!important` to the style you wish to use to override, like so: `color: #fff!important;`

Comment: Sure, thanks for the explanation. I was able to solve the issue by creating a custom stylesheet and overridden the specific style.